# Long Run Model of Oligopolies After Recession

Tags: microeconomics, oligopoly, covid-19-crisis, long-run, recession

I am currently investigating about the long run impact of the COVID 19 to the US airline industry. Is there any specific (long-run) model that I can use for oligopolies (for 4 main companies)? Because I knew that not all models describe the same situation in an oligopoly market.

Would price discrimination / economies of scale / demand-supply graph enough to explain the long-term decisions of the airlines?

Comment: Hi! What exactly are you trying to do? "impact to the industry" is very broad, no single model is going to give you that. Is this for a thesis, peer reviewed research, a newspaper article, for your own entertainment without demand for accuracy...? Also maybe give some information about your level of familiarity with industrial organization/forecasting literature, as most answers are likely to recommend some advanced models.

Comment: it's for a university essay. So basically answering the question of how US airlines can maximize profit after the Covid-19 pandemic in the long-run.

Comment: What class is this? Business strategy, microeconomics (BA, MA), etc.? Sounds like a very broad topic.

Comment: it's microeconomics